# I want a discord bot send a dm to somebody by their id

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
if (message.content === "!test"){
 client.users.cache.get('id').send('message');
 console.log("message sent")
}
```

This method doesn't work and I wasn't able to find any other methods that worked
Is there a spelling mistake or this method is outdated?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: You should check what `client.users.cache.get('id')` returns. If I provide a valid ID, your code works fine, if it's invalid, `client.users.cache.get('id')` returns undefined, so you will receive a TypeError, like _"Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"_

Answer (score 0):

I've actually encountered this error myself once. There are two problems you might be facing here:

- The user isn't cached by discord.js yet
- There isn't a `DMChannel` open for that user yet

To solve the first one, you have to **fetch** the user before doing anything with it. Remember this is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you'll have to either `await` for it to complete or use `.then(...)`.

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch('id')
```

Once you've fetched your user by their ID, you can then create a `DMChannel` which, again, returns a promise.

```js
const dmChannel = await user.createDM()
```

You can then use your channel like you normally would

```js
dmChannel.send('Hello!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a variable like this:

```
var user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.id === 'USER-ID')
```

And then do this:

```
user.send('your message')
```

Comment: There won't be any difference if the user is not cached.